# Mocking Jdbctemplate using H2 db gives error

Tags: java, junit, mockito, h2, jdbctemplate

Hi I am trying to mock jdbc template `queryForObject` method . I am using H2 InMem Db.

Following is the error

```
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Method is only allowed for a query. Use execute or executeUpdate instead of executeQuery; SQL statement:
 [90002-196]
```

Below is the code snippet.

```
EmbeddedDatabase db = new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder()
                           .setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.H2)
                           .addScript("table.sql").build();`

JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate();
jdbcTemplate.setDataSource(db);
jdbcTemplate.execute("insert into AlertTypeHeader  values " +
                "(1234,365537,'TestAT','ExtId',123,345,null,null,2,0)");
when(jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(anyString(), new Object[]{},ResultSet::getObject)).thenReturn(RequiredObject);
```

Comment: because your jdbcTemplate object is not a mock. You are creating a new object instead of a mock `JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate();`

Answer (score 1):

the problem is that you are not using a mock, so you are running `when` on a real object

```
JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate();
```

should be replaced with:

```
JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = Mockito.mock(JdbcTemplate.class);
```

Comment: I changed as above but still the same error. org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Method is only allowed for a query. Use execute or executeUpdate instead of executeQuery; SQL statement:
 [90002-196]

Comment: However , I changed the approach to not to include embedded db and just use Mockito to return desired the object.